# File location for unit testing

Tags: java, android, file-io, junit4

This is a very simple question which I cannot find a solution for. I have a quite complex Android app which uses the camera and does some manipulations to the images taken. I now want to write Unit tests for some of the functions but I cannot get a file loaded.

In an Android test project where should I paste the Image to test on and how can I load that image into a `File` object? I have a normal `junit.framework.TestCase` class that needs to send a `File` to an class to test on. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may not be the best solution since it could bloat your project considerably. However, short of writing code to download an image in your test cases, I'm not sure what other approach there might be.

Simply, i have 'test' drawables in my resources and I load them as bitmaps, then store them somewhere on the disc to finally reference them in my tests. This is the code I use:

```
public File saveResourceImageToExternalStorage(Activity activity, String picFileName, int imageId)
{
    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(activity.getResources(), imageId);
    File picFile = null;
    OutputStream os = null;
    try
    {
        picFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), picFileName);

        picFile.createNewFile();

        os = new FileOutputStream(picFile);

        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, os);
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return file;
}
```

You'll probably want to make that method a little more robust.

Finally, you could just stash your test images in your assets folder for your project. Then you can get them from your assets folder using `getAssets()` in an Activity or using the path which should be something like `file:///android_asset/your_file_name.jpg`

**EDIT**

I think a better solution, after some research, would be to add your files to the assets of your test project and use `InputStream input = this.getContext().getAssets().open("file.jpg");`. You need to call this from a class that inherits from `InstrumentationTestCase` or, I suppose, `ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2`. You can then manipulate the input stream how you need

Comment: This is definitely not ideal. Ideally I would like to have the images in the test project but alas this it seems that this is what I have to do.

Comment: After a bit of research it seems it would be much simpler to add your files in the assets of your test project and use InputStream input = this.getContext().getAssets().open("file.jpg");. You need to call this from a class that inherits from InstrumentationTestCase or, I suppose, ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2. You can then manipulate the input stream how you need.

Comment: Thank you. That is the type of answer that I was looking for. Can you please make it an answer/update your answer so that I can mark it.